# Is mutation safe on a static variable from multiple thread in crystal-lang?

Tags: deadlock, crystal-lang

Consider this example -

```
class Test
   @@store = ""
end
```

Here store is a class variable of `Test` and can be mutated from anywhere.

Suppose i am runing my program in multi thread mode & so variable store can be mutated from multiple thread at a time.

My question is - will deadlock arise or crystal-lang handles it in some way due to fiber scheduling ?

If deadlock arises what is the recommended way to solve above program. If you can provide a code from this problem, that would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a deadlock would not arise since Crystal does no implicit locking around variable access. But it's very easy to write thread unsafe code with global state like this.

BAD EXAMPLE:

```
module Test
  @@store = "a"

  def self.run
    spawn do
      @@store = @@store == "a" ? "b" : "c"
    end

    @@store = @@store == "b" ? "d" : "e"
  end
end

Test.run
```

When running this program with multithreading `@@store` might either be `"b"`, `"c"`, `"d"` or `"e"` at the end of the program (in practice you'll see all but one result very rarely because there's not a lot going on and not a lot of contention, so it will be quite stable within an execution environment).

Crystal provides some synchronization primitives such as `Mutex` and `Atomic`, but the general recommendation is to prefer passing immutable data over `Channel`s rather than mutable data sharing between fibers.